# How to do Exception Handling in Wicket

Tags: java, spring, wicket

I've read that wicket can't throw Checked exception. how to deal with this? What is a good way to implement exception handling in Wicket spring based application?

Mac

Comment: I would suggest to make the queastion a bit more specific. Wicket is a Java framework, you can do exception handling the way you do in other projects. If there is a special case in wicket maybe mention it with an example and ask for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean, "Wicket can't throw".  [citation needed] :)

Perhaps you read somewhere that wicket will not pass an exception to the servlet container in the default configuration?

I usually wrap specific components' methods with a `try` and change the page appropriately in `catch`, i.e. telling the user that something went wrong.

*Update:*
And also, you have the `error()`, `warn()` etc. in every `Component` which works with Feedback stuff. See [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/error-pages-and-feedback-messages.html).